# Is there a way to re-sequence related tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-migration

I need to "archive" data from 2 connected tables, in order to anonymise customer data.

In order to do that I'll do a `INSERT....SELECT` from  TABLE1 and TABLE2 into two others identical tables: TABLE1_anonymous, TABLE2_anonymous.

The primary key of TABLE1 will change with autoincrement, but what about TABLE2?
I'll lose the relationship.

Is there a known way to do this?

My only idea is to avoid autoincrement, leave the original id at first, and after run an update on both tables with a random id...

Comment: the secondary anonymous tables don't need a autoincrement. copy imp,y the ids from the originals

Comment: @nbk, with which ids? I must known how the primary key of the first table has changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE1_anonymous (fields except id)
SELECT (fields except id)
FROM TABLE1;

INSERT INTO TABLE2_anonymous (fields except id and table1_id), table1_id
SELECT (fields from TABLE2 except id and table1_id),       
       TABLE1_anonymous.id
FROM TABLE1
JOIN TABLE1_anonymous USING (fields except id)
JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.id = TABLE2.table1_id;
```

The JOINs in last query allows you to replace `id` value in source table, which `table1_id` is referenced to, with newly assigned auto_incremented `id` value from anonymous table copy.

---

Alternatively you may alter anonymous table structires, add `old_id` field, insert `id` values into it during copy, then restore referencing integrity using this values, and finally drop there fields.